# Open .FID file from benchtop NMR Oxford Instruments

Tags: binary, decoding, spectra

I have been working for a while with NMR data from a benchtop machine from Oxford Instruments in MESTRENOVA. This software lets me do some interesting analysis, but I want to do more personalized scripts with either PYTHON or MATLAB. The problem is, I have been trying to open the .FID files from the machine, which contain all my data, and I am not making any progress.

These files are perfectly opened within MESTRENOVA, without the need of any other extra parameter file, which is the case for other types of NMR data. I know the data is somehow binary encoded, and that it contains a header with some of the needed parameters to obtain the data as I want it.

For now, I have tried to open the files using various scripts from other people without any result. I have also tried to open it in python using different decoding possibilities, and although I obtain something that kind of makes sense, it is still far from the data I want to see. The desired result is as follows:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zhRY.png)

What I have managed to obtain is the following:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xk4rs.png)
By using the following code:
float64_array = np.fromfile(file_path, dtype='float16') %I have tried other dtypes, but this is the one with the closest result to my desired data
plt.plot(float64_array)

I have also tried to use some toolboxes like matNMR, or nmrglue, but neithwer of them work for my specific type of data.

If someone has some expertise on the field, or knows how to open this data, it would be very helpful.
Thanks in advance!